# Why is my JQuery UI Datepicker only translated when it is clicked?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, localization, calendar

This line is on top of my JavaScript and executed:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['de']);
});
```

I initialize my calendar in the same file inside the document-ready function:

```
// #transports-calendar is a div
$("#transports-calendar").datepicker({
    onSelect: function() {
        // Some stuff
    }
});
```

On my HTML page the following scripts are included:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.dialogextend.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.blockUI.js" type="text/javascript"></script>        
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js" type="text/javascript"></script>            
<script src="/Scripts/tooltip.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/tooltip.dynamic.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/tooltip.slide.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/core-functionality.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   
<script src="/Scripts/core-extensions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script src="/ModuleScripts/jquery.ui.datepicker-de.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Everything is okay, but as mentioned in the title, the DatePicker is only translated when it is clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something that might be worth a try is to apply the regional settings when you call the datepicker function like so:

```
$("#transports-calendar").datepicker(
    $.datepicker.regional['de']
);
```

Then set the onselect event like so...

```
$("#transports-calendar").datepicker("option", "onSelect", function (date) {
   // Some stuff
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try it and report back.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#transports-calendar").datepicker({
    onSelect: function() {
        // Some stuff
    }
});

$("#transports-calendar").trigger('click');
```

Comment: i do no why. if do this it will be triggered. u can put ticket in jquery ui. they will tell the solution.

Comment: The click event doesn't appear to be triggered.

Comment: u r using image button for datepicker?

Comment: No, the datepicker is loaded in a div

Comment: Do you use this inside your html page or in an external JS file?. Try to set defaults inside jsp/html page.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to manually `setDefault` a translation as it happens automatically when you include the translation js file.

I'm somewhat concerned about all the js files you are including.  Do these files contain the same thing?  Especially considering you are also including the individual plugin files too.  They could be conflicting with each other?

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui/ui/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.js"></script>
```

The Datepicker settings are changed instantly when you call `setDefault`. however they are not used until they are needed such as when it is clicked to be displayed or when you call a method on it.

There is also the `.datepicker("refresh")` which will force a redraw of the date picker.  That method is not called automatically with `setDefault` but may be what you actually need.

Comment: I updated the list of scripts that are now included. I tried the manual refresh, but it doesn't change the results.